# How can I change the priority of a Windows service process?

Tags: windows-xp, process, sp3, windows-search, priority

I would like to run the Windows Desktop Search indexer at below normal priority. When I try to set this via task manager, I get 'Access is denied'.

Is there a way to remove whatever restrictions are protecting this process? Or ideally, configure it to have the lower priority on startup?

XPSP3 btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in as Administrator, give [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) a go. I've changed priority of processes before that Task Manager was unable to change.

If you don't really need it you can turn it off altogether (Go to the properties of your `C:\` drive, and uncheck "Allow indexing service to index this drive for fast file searching" then hit apply). [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) from void tools is much faster for finding files.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it already has low priority, but chews up resources anyway.

From http://kadaitcha.cx/performance.html:

> On a new system, the indexing service
>   can take days to settle down. This is
>   because the service puts a low
>   priority on its work. Despite this low
>   priority, the indexing service can
>   cause serious performance degradation,
>   especially in lower-end machines
>   because the computer's hard disk runs
>   continuously